# Python module global variables

Tags: python, pyserial

I have a following code but I want to transform it into module. 
Obviously if I miport this code as module `ser_r` and `ser` will never be initialized and the `Agent` class won't work.

```
#module.py

class Agent:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def send(self, data):
        message = data + ' ' + a
        ser.write(message)

ser_r = serial.Serial(
                    port='COM6',
                    baudrate=500000,
                    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
                    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
                    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
                    )

ser = io.TextIOWrapper(io.BufferedRWPair(self.ser_raw, self.ser_raw, 1),
                   newline='\r',
                   line_buffering=True)
```

So I came up with the idea to create class `Serial` which has `ser` variable which is then used in `Agent` class.

But now there is another problem: How do I access `Serial` inside `Agent` without creating instance of `Serial`? The user can create a `Serial` instance but then I don't know the name I should use inside `Agent`. I can make `init` method and then create `Serial` class inside. After importing user would call `init` method and then he could use it.

```
#module.py

class Agent:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def send(self, data):
        message = data + ' ' + a
        Serial.ser.write(message)



class Serial:
    ser_r = serial.Serial(
                port='COM6',
                baudrate=500000,
                parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
                stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
                bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
            )

    ser = io.TextIOWrapper(io.BufferedRWPair(self.ser_raw, self.ser_raw, 1),
                               newline='\r',
                               line_buffering=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

> Obviously if I import this code as module `ser_r` and `ser` will never be initialized and `Agent` class won't work.

No, that's not obvious at all, and in fact wrong. Importing a module runs **all top-level code**. There is no problem here, `ser_r` and `ser` are created along with everything else.

Classes are not special here; `class Serial: ...` is just another top-level statement, *just like the `ser_r` and `ser` assigment statements*.

Note that the module forms the *global namespace* for all code in that module. In `Agent.send()`, the name `ser` is a global, and that name is resolved by looking at the attached module globals where `ser` will already exist.

You do have an error in the code, however:

```
ser = io.TextIOWrapper(io.BufferedRWPair(self.ser_raw, self.ser_raw, 1),
                   newline='\r',
                   line_buffering=True)
```

There is no global name `self` defined, so `self.ser_raw` doesn't exist either. Perhaps you meant to create the wrapper around `ser_r` instead?

```
ser = io.TextIOWrapper(io.BufferedRWPair(ser_r, ser_r, 1),
                       newline='\r', line_buffering=True)
```

This all means you don't actually have to use the `Serial` class. It has no state (only class attributes), so you'd never need to create an instance anyway, you could just treat it as a global (as your second attempt *already does*). Because you *already* have access to the `Serial` global from `Agent().send()`, there is no need for anyone using your module to have to know about `Serial` or create an instance of it.

If you do not want to make the serial connection a global, you could always create the connection in `Agent.__init__()`, or have that class accept a suitable `io.TextIOBase` object to write to.